# Get calls from log by specific SIM

Tags: android, telephonymanager, calllog

I want to get calls from Android CallLog.Calls which were made from a specific SIM. Is there's a way to check which SIM was used to make call?
The following method allows to check SIM when call is performed and app is running.
`(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE).getSimSerialNumber();`
How to check which SIM was used to make calls before app is installed?

Answer (score 0):

In the [CallLog.Calls](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html) class, there don't seems any field that keeps SIM Information (like which SIM is used while making an outgoing call).

So, I guess it make no difference if your app was installed or not installed, the Call Log Content provider does not seems to maintain SIM-Sepcific, such as from which SIM the call has been initiated.

Comment: Does it mean that if user changes SIM card in a single-SIM device, it's impossible to check which one was used to make a call from log?

Comment: i guess you may try `telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber();` to get SIM serial number which  is unique within the operator. Save this value and later if you change the SIM card, it should return you different value. This way, in a single-SIM device, you can still obtain info. I myself didn't try that though but worth trying once I guess, if it is your core functionality

Comment: @ AADTechnical, thanks for the advice, it works. But I need to know if it's possible to check which SIM was used to make a call before app is installed.

Comment: AFAIK, this can only be acheived by "sticky" broadcast , to which  your app can query as and when it is installed on device. But I never heard of any Android system broadcast that populates SIM Info when SIM is added/pulled from Device, which is STICKY. There is a Broadcast in Android when SIM state change `android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED` .....but your app can only get it when it is already installed on device.