# Get call log by sim slot in Marshmallow and below android

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, calllog, dual-sim

I want to get call log history by sim slot number. Like this image:

[image: Call Details want to fetch]

For that I searched many sites till I got:

```
Cursor managedCursor = getActivity().managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, strOrder);
int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
int account = 0;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    account = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.PHONE_ACCOUNT_COMPONENT_NAME);//for versions above lollipop
    ac_id = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID);

}
```

**Currently getting PHONE_ACCOUNT_COMPONENT_NAME and PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID as per the android documentation but how to use it to get sim slot**

Followed this links :

[Samsung android 6.0 how to get dual sim call logs with sim slot id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36711454/samsung-android-6-0-how-to-get-dual-sim-call-logs-with-sim-slot-id)

[Get calls from log by specific SIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28297245/get-calls-from-log-by-specific-sim)

[How to get carrier name from dual sim phone Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714656/how-to-get-carrier-name-from-dual-sim-phone-android)

[Programmatically retrieve IMEI number for dual SIM in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524413/programmatically-retrieve-imei-number-for-dual-sim-in-android/32304799#32304799)

but none of them worked for me.

I got the names of both current sim in dual sim in api>21 using SubscriptionManager Class but unable to check it in call log.

Kindly suggest me better way to do that.

Comment: Find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the following column in the CallLog: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID

Ensure you have the following permission set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

Then add the following Java code to get the column:

```
Uri allCalls = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
Cursor c = managedQuery(allCalls, null, null, null, null);
String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID));
```

Comment: thanks, i found that but can you please post some code or small example.

Comment: @VishalDalve Please see the edited code - I added an example. Please upvote my answer if you found it helpful, it would mean a lot. Thank you!

Comment: If you saw my question properly, the answer you gave is already done by myself. I want next part of my question. And I already accepted your answer. Thank you.